# props is undefined in react js when used in the child class

Tags: reactjs

im trying to send a value from parent class to child but for some reason im getting props undefined any help?
 this is parent class and sending the data to child.
I have added the full child code as requested. im not sure how to add props in as it is a function and when i tried adding props in im still getting props undefined error

```
{this.state.viewProfile ? (
                <SideProfileDrawer
                  people={this.state.people}
                  viewprof={this.state.viewProfile}
                />
              ) : null}
```

here is me using the props in child

```
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InstructionsModal from "./instructionsmodal";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom";
import UserProfile from "../quiz/userProfile";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Test from "../quiz/test";

export default function TemporaryDrawer(props) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    list: {
      width: 680
    },
    fullList: {
      width: "auto"
    }
  });
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    top: false,
    left: false,
    bottom: false,
    right: false
  });

  const toggleDrawer = (side, open) => event => {
    if (
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
  };

  const sideList = side => (
    <div
      className={classes.list}
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
    >
      {this.props.people.map((person, index) => {
        return (
          <UserProfile
            className="userProfile"
            levelRook={person.levelRook}
            levelStudent={person.levelStudent}
            levelIntermediate={person.levelIntermediate}
            levelExpert={person.levelExpert}
            levelMaster={person.levelMaster}
            score={person.Score}
            question={person.Questions}
            email={person.email}
            time={person.lastLogin}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.viewprof?sideList:null}
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer("right", true)}>Open Right</Button>

      <Drawer
        anchor="right"
        open={state.right}
        onClose={toggleDrawer("right", false)}
      >
        {sideList("right")}
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help in solving this i tried everything

Comment: please share the full code of your child component

Comment: Your component is not a class component, but a functional component. you can access it with `side.people` instead of `this.props.people`

Comment: @Chris would that accces the data im sending from parent tho?

Comment: @Chris once i done that i get map function is undefined

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah i have added the full child component code

Comment: Oh, I see now. try just `props`, without the `this`

Comment: ok @Chris yes it worked now thank bro do u know y that works without this?

Comment: You should read about the differences between a class component and a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

don't use **this.props** just use **props** as you have stateless component not stateful [read more](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/stateful-stateless-components-react/)

Comment: Has nothing to do with the statefulness of the component.

Comment: no, what I mean is the child component is not a class its functional component and stateful and stateless  is an old term to denote this

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of the article you linked. It's overlapping state and class/function components, which aren't the same thing

Comment: Yeah, because before react hooks the only way to have a state was with class components. Now you can though with hooks, as OP actually uses.

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel https://medium.com/@cgcrutch18/stateful-vs-stateless-react-components-13f647f7fc4 check this out may you find it usefull

Comment: Then checkout [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). The point is that You can write stateless class component as well as stateful function components. They're just two different things